# How can I position my hamburger menu and its drop down on the right side at the same time with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my links on the right with no navbar on the left.

When the screen gets smaller I want the hamburger to replace these links without moving to the left side.

I added `<a href="#"></a>` as sort of a logo placeholder which pushed the hamburger menu to the right, but the menu is still opening to the left.

Here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler left:auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon ml-auto"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-auto" id="navbarMenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what are you asking for
or
i'm not understanding your question

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler left:auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon ml-auto"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-auto" id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item ml-auto"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item ml-auto"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item ml-auto"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ahh... Yeah, that's what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: no problem man, could you accept the answer and close the thread? would be nice.

Comment: How do I close the thread? I can only find information on how to delete it. Is that what you mean?